# Add browser name to the json result produced by cucumber java

Tags: java, json, selenium, cucumber-jvm

Is there a way to add the browser name as a additional field to the json result produced by cucumber java using selenium.

Answer (score 0):

Sure.  Cosider the following:

```
import cucumber.api.Scenario;

public class MyStepdefs {
    private Scenario scenario;
    private WebDriver driver;

    @Before
    public void before(Scenario scenario) {
        this.scenario = scenario;
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }

    @Given("^I have (\\d+) cukes in my belly$")
    public void cukes_in_my_belly(int cukes) {
         Capabilities cap = ((RemoteWebDriver) driver).getCapabilities();
         String browsername = cap.getBrowserName();
         scenario.write("Browser is " + browsername + "\n");
    }
}
```

You can read the official post [here](https://gist.github.com/aslakhellesoy/4072962)

**EDIT**

The json part is controlled by your cucumber options.

```
@CucumberOptions(plugin = {"pretty", "json:target2/cucumber.json"}, ...)
```

Comment: Not really the exact answer that Connor was asking for, but close.

Comment: @djangofan How so?